# How to stop program from waiting for a client to connect when using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server, port

I have been trying to make a server that a client can connect to in python using sockets. The problem is that I need the server to not wait for the connection as i need it to do other functions as well.
Any code past the `server.accept` will not execute until the client connects to the server.

```
import socket

server = socket.socket
host = ""
port = 1234
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen(5)
client, adress = server.accept() # has to wait for connection from client
#other functions
```

I have look it up but i could not find anything.
Thank you,
Matthew.

Comment: There are lots of solutions, including [select/poll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html), [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). You'll find examples of all of those with a little searching.